# Datastudio + Bigquery Timestamp not working with Year - Week format

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp, looker-studio

I have a timestamp column in query with format "2019-03-18 17:17:07.543200 UTC
", the default timestamp format for Bigquery standard SQL.

When triying to plot a chart displaying the date as Year and week, I get this error
"Syntax error: Unexpected ")" at [1:817]"

I don't understand since it's the default timestamp format, the one returned with current_timestamp() in Bigquery... and it works  with all the others combinations (day, month, year, yearmonth, year quarter.....)

Any hints??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

do extract year and WEEK  from timestamp

```
select  EXTRACT(YEAR from timestamp),EXTRACT(WEEK from timestamp)
```